# How can I pass a value to Formik's component part in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik, formik-material-ui

I want to pass enabled or disabled value with true or false to Formik's component , but when I give like this

```
<Formik 
enableddisabled={true}
component={ContactForm} />;
```

its not receiving in `ContactForm component`, its showing undefined

how do I pass `enabledisabled` into `ContactForm` Component and get it in contact form component so I can use that there for further checking?

Comment: show me your `ContactForm` and the whole file where this `Formik` part is written

Comment: I have some security to reasons to show the file that's why I put dummy as an example to know how I can pass values

Comment: I understand. See, `component={ContactForm}` should work. Make sure `ContactForm`'s render part is correct

Comment: thank you for your time, that's all working correct.. I called enable disabled as` const {  enabledisabled } = this.props;`

Comment: as props in contact form ... but its not getting there :(